# Simics package repository

Tags: simics

I'm developing a light kernel for hobby.
Currently I use QEMU as simulation platform. Recently I downloaded and played a bit with the  preview of the public release of Simics.
I would like to migrate my project to this platform to try to take advantage of some amazing features it offers like reverse execution.
My problem is the preview platform supports new hardware only whereas my project runs on old one.
Basically to run my project I need a 440bx based environment. I know Simics supports it, the package should be something like simics-x86-440bx-6.0.0.
Anyway If I understood correctly, this package is not included in the preview release.
My question: is there some public repository from where to download the packages not included in the preview installation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no additional model packages available for download.

What software do you have that cannot run on the (also pretty old) ICH10/X58 platform?

#IAmAIntel

Comment: Can I run under ICH10 drivers written for 8259 pic ,IDE disk,8253 pit and intel 825xx ethernet card?

Comment: Also for keyboard I have 8042.

Comment: I think (but I don't have my Simics handy right now) that such legacy peripherals are present in the ICH10. The legacy block tends to stay around to ensure backwards compatibility.  Try it and see how ít goes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the ICH10 datasheet and indeed all the old hardware is supported. My only doubt is regarding 8042. ICH10 should emulate old 8042 protocol using the so called "USB legacy keyboard" but I didn't understand if this function requires special setup on the BIOS or no. Anyway, at this point, I think the best thing to do is try to run my code on Simics and see what happens.

Comment: I'm trying to boot my image on Simics. At the moment I'm stuck in trying to switch from UEFI to legacy BIOS. I also opened a specific question on that. Could you help me out?

Comment: Please boot from UEFI, not legacy BIOS.  Legacy BIOS is really no longer supported.